# Creating a 2D array from a 1D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
let numbers = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];
```

I create a new array without the duplicate values:

```
let counter = [...new Set(array)]; 
//Output: [ 10, 20, 30, 50 ]
```

I want to instantiate the counter array as a 2D/nested array so that it looks like this:

```
//counter output: [[10,4][20, 3][30, 1][50,1]]
```

What's the best way to do this? The numbers array could have various elements and therefore the number of elements in the counter array could vary.

Comment: What does the second number in each sub-array represent and why are they all `0`?

Comment: `counter.map(c => [ c, 0 ])`?

Comment: The 0 will be a tally of the corresponding values in the numbers array. By the end of the application, the counter array will look like this: [[10,4][20, 3][30, 1][50,1]]. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your question would have made a lot more sense if you'd given a better example in the first place

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for the original question (how to create an array of `[[10, 0],[20, 0],[30, 0],[50, 0]]` from the Set):

Instead of spreading the Set, use `Array.from()` to create an array of pairs:

```js
const numbers = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

const counter = Array.from(new Set(numbers), v => [v, 0]);

console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want that second sub-array index to represent the number of occurrences of each number (*ed: confirmed now*), you can collect the counts into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and then convert that to an array

```js
let numbers = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

const counter = [...numbers.reduce((map, n) => 
  map.set(n, (map.get(n) ?? 0) + 1), new Map())]
  
console.info(JSON.stringify(counter)) // stringifying so it's all on one line
```

The array conversion works since `Map` supports the common *entries* format of

```js
[ [ key, value ], [ key, value ], ... ]
```

and using spread syntax implicitly converts it to an *entries* array.

Comment: @OriDrori I thought it was odd that OP's array was called _counter_

Answer (score 0):

One way is take the ideas you have already used and map across those values returning new arrays with the value and an additional zero.

```
let numbers = [...new Set([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20])].map(value=>[value,0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your original array into an object (hash map) to keep track of the count. And then convert it into to `Object.entries()` array.

```js
const numbers = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

let obj = {};
numbers.forEach(n => {
    obj[n] = obj[n] || 0;
    obj[n]++;
});
const counter = Object.entries(obj).map(e => [+e[0], e[1]]);

console.log(counter);
```